# Component driven design architecture - communication between components

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture, components

I am building a game using Unity3D and I have a question about how to structure my actors architecture(with actors I mean objects that can interact with other objects in one way or another).

So, I have followed a component-driven design with each component responsible for handling different aspects of an object(for example animation component, movement component, attacker component etc) but I'm having trouble deciding how the components should communicate with each other. My thoughts are :

1. Each object has a component manager that holds references to each component attached on the object. The components communicate with each other through the references of the component manager.
2. Each component is responsible to hold it's own references and handle communication internally. Drawback I can think of is that multiple components will hold the same references.
3. Communication is handled using an automated messaging system.(Events and listeners)

**My questions are : Are there better ways to handle component communication?
                     What are the benefits or downsides of each way?**

p.s I'm not asking about Unity or language specific answers just a minor push to the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Each object has a component manager that holds references to each
> component attached on the object. The components communicate with each
> other through the references of the component manager.
>
> Communication is handled using an automated messaging system.(Events
> and listeners)

I'd say go for a mix between these two. Having a component manager for each object will be helpful especially when adding new components in the future. Just make a reference field for this new one in the manager and you're done. Also the manager can act as an entry point between an external entity and the manager's components.

Conversely, having objects hold their own references to other components is definitely bad since you will have to assign references on all the components when a new component comes in. Plus that probably won't make the components work independently of each other because they are going to have to access each others functions,properties or variables at some point in time.

Using events to communicate between the components of the same object might not be a good idea. There will be situations where you might want to call a function and use it's return value to determine whether to proceed or not. For example suppose the player has a chance of blocking an incoming attack and player UI should only be updated if the attack was successful. You can do something like

```
void OnPlayerDamagedCommon() {
    bool damaged = PlayerDefense.OnPlayerDamaged();
    PlayerUI.OnPlayerDamaged(damaged);
}
```

However events will be really useful when communicating between different objects. For example the player can trigger the `OnAttack` event when an attack has been performed and all the enemies who have subscribed to this event can respond accordingly. Also, any kind of entity can subscribe to an event. Be an enemy, a NPC or an environmental object. This will make it easier to localize behavior logic.

You can also use interfaces to add one object to a processing list of another object.

```
class Enemy : IShootable {
    void Enemy() { 
        playerManager.AddToShootable(this); 
        public void OnShoot() {...}    
    }
}

class PlayerAttack {
    void OnShoot () {
        foreach(IShootable s in _shootableList) {
            if(CheckRaycast(s)) 
            { 
                s.OnShoot() 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This helps to localize the code to determine whether an  enemy has been hit to a single place, rather than each enemy having its own raycast check code, as would have been the case if you were using events

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply it's been really helpful!

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Each object has a component manager that holds references to each component attached on the object.

This is already possible if the component inherits from MonoBehaviour. There is the GetComponent() which gets the component from a GameObject, this works for scripts as well as components.

Is there any particular reason you wish to make your own management system instead of using the decoupled built-in one?

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: Actually there's not. I guess I'm just overthinking this since it's my first time using this design architecture. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Glad to help and don't worry, the understanding will come in time. Since you are new here, allow me to bid you welcome to Stackoverflow.

Notice that you can read more about how Stackoverflow works at the Help Center if you wish to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @ΕρωτόκριτοςΒαλλιανάτος, This link may be useful for you if you are new to Unity, it is an overview of Unity's lifecycle methods such as Start and Update, when they will be called in the game engine. https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/monobehaviour_flowchart.svg